# How to install Guest Additions in VrtualBox OpenSuse

Tags: installation, guest-additions, guest

How to install Guest Additions in VrtualBox OpenSuse? tapping "Insert Guest Additions" in Devices does not install, the installation process ends with errors "kernel headers not found for target kernel 5.014.8-1-default. Please install them and execute /sbin/rcvboxadd setup.
Running kernel modules will not be replaced until the system is restarted

Comment: Then install the kernel headers/source? What can you not understand?

Comment: How do I install kernel headers/source?

Comment: `su -`, then pop in the root password, then run `yast2 sw_single`, then search for `kernel` and install what is required.

Comment: It's `yast2 sw_single`, not `yast2 sw-single`. Underscore, not dash.

Comment: After doing so it still gives the same errors
kernel headers not found for target kernel 5.014.8-1-default. Please install them and execute /sbin/rcvboxadd setup. Running kernel modules will not be replaced until the system is restarted

Comment: Here's a screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pt__NLdshrn-Wk4j2Xb0wlsPsG2zkFmT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Post the output of `rpm -qa | grep ^kernel`. Post the output of `/etc/os-release`. Edit your question to show both of these.

Comment: How do I insert this command "/etc/os-release"?

Comment: `cat /etc/os-release`. It's a text file.

Comment: You have to get a grip on what you are doing. Don't post images. The ouput of the rpm command is just text. Add it to your question. And do not restrict it to the last few lines.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12E_dKMjzktYG59pVGQdMNxkryTXxtCXf/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11a9y8DEeEQ9dftO0LelobZ7iIO2f1Llb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Will you please stop posting images. It's text, so please add the output to your question.

Comment: Guest Additions is not installed so I cannot copy all the text

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WgQqqzrS1mkEZ1iBvwsT-41qirJPJSqK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: `Guest Additions is not installed so I cannot copy all the text` is the wrong answer. You can direct it to a file then scp it to your host. And here is some advice. Since your knowledge of Linux appears minimal, do not use tumbleweed. Instead install the 15.3 release. If you looked at the output, you'll see a discrepancy between 5.014.8-1 & 5.14.8-1.1.

Comment: I cannot copy anything to the host without Guest Additions

Comment: From your host run `scp` to your guest. It does not require guest additions to be installed. If you do not have scp on your host, then install putty.

Comment: How do I work with putty? can you give detailed steps?

Comment: Forget tumbleweed and install 15.3.

Comment: My question now is how to install kernel header

Comment: And I see that a lot of users have this problem

Comment: I told you earlier.

Comment: I did what you told earlier did not help

Comment: Have you installed opensuse 15.3?

Comment: When I use command zypper dup it gives me 4 problems and when I cose option 1 to solve it runs the update and asks to reboot and after rebooting and I run zypper dup again the same 4 problems occur again, seemingly that it does not update.
this is the output:

Comment: This is the 4 problems:     4 Problems:
Problem: problem with the installed libtracker-common-2_0-2.3.6-21.2.x86_64
Problem: problem with the installed libtracker-control-2_0-0-2.3.6-21.2.x86_64
Problem: problem with the installed libtracker-sparql-2_0-0-2.3.6-21.2.x86_64
Problem: problem with the installed tracker2-2.3.6-21.2.x86_64

Problem: problem with the installed libtracker-common-2_0-2.3.6-21.2.x86_64
 Solution 1: install libtracker-common-2_0-2.3.6-4.1.x86_64 from vendor openSUSE
  replacing libtracker-common-2_0-2.3.6-21.2.x86_64 from vendor obs://build.opensuse.org/GNOME
 S

Comment: Solution 2: keep obsolete libtracker-common-2_0-2.3.6-21.2.x86_64

Choose from above solutions by number or skip, retry or cancel [1/2/s/r/c/d/?] (c):

Comment: Delete every libtracker.

Comment: I purged them and the 4 problems disappeared, but after rebooting and doing the zyper dup command again they all reappeared

Comment: Why are you continually doing an upgrade? Have you installed 15.3?

Comment: Downloading it now

Comment: Installed 15.3 and the same error displays, I also installed ZorinOS 16, and there was no errors

Comment: After all updates OpenSUSE 15.3 Guest Additions is working but Tumbleweed remains with errors.

Answer (score 0):

The [Virtualbox manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/) has a chapter dedicated to the [Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html). [4.2.2 Guest Additions for Linux](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#additions-linux) is where we can find more information on your question. Under header 4.2.2.1 we can read the following on installing guest additions under linux

> Before installing the Guest Additions, you prepare your guest system for building external kernel modules.

And it even points us to another chapter in the manual, namely [The Oracle VM Virtualbox  Kernel Modules](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html#externalkernelmodules). This tells us the big prerequisit is usually the following

> GNU compiler (GCC)
>
> GNU Make (make)
>
> Kernel header files

So now we know *why* you are getting errors, how do we go about installing the guest additions specificly for OpenSuse. Unfortunately, i'm more of a Debian guy, so i set  out to do a google search and found [How to Install VirtualBox Guest Additions on openSUSE](https://linuxnightly.com/how-to-install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-opensuse/), which kindly shows us which commands to run specificly under opensuse

> $ sudo zypper refresh
>
> $ sudo zypper update
>
> $ sudo zypper in kernel-devel gcc make

Now run the installer again and you should be good. Reboot the system and enable the guest addition features you would like to use.

Comment: After executing these 3 commands the same errors occurs